# The signature for this packaged module couldn't be inferred in recursive function

Tags: module, ocaml, first-class-modules, locally-abstract-type

I'm still trying to figure out how to split code when using mirage and it's myriad of first class modules.
I've put everything I need in a big ugly `Context` module, to avoid having to pass ten modules to all my functions, one is pain enough.

I have a function to receive commands over tcp :

```
let recvCmds (type a) (module Ctx : Context with type chan = a) nodeid chan = ...
```

After hours of trial and errors, I figured out that I needed to add `(type a)` and the "explicit" `type chan = a` to make it work. Looks ugly, but it compiles.
But if I want to make that function recursive :

```
let rec recvCmds (type a) (module Ctx : Context with type chan = a) nodeid chan =
  Ctx.readMsg chan >>= fun res ->
  ... more stuff ...
  |> OtherModule.getStorageForId (module Ctx)
  ... more stuff ...
  recvCmds (module Ctx) nodeid chan
```

I pass the module twice, the first time no problem but
I get an error on the recursion line :

```
The signature for this packaged module couldn't be inferred.
```

and if I try to specify the signature I get

```
This expression has type a but an expression was expected of type 'a
The type constructor a would escape its scope
```

And it seems like I can't use the whole `(type chan = a)` thing.
If someone could explain what is going on, and ideally a way to work around it, it'd be great.
I could just use a while of course, but I'd rather finally understand these damn modules. Thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pratical answer is that recursive functions should universally quantify their locally abstract types with `let rec f: type a. .... = fun ...` .

More precisely, your example can be simplified to

```
module type T = sig type t end 
let rec f (type a) (m: (module T with type t = a)) = f m
```

which yield the same error as yours:

> Error: This expression has type (module T with type t = a)
>          but an expression was expected of type 'a
>          The type constructor a would escape its scope

This error can be fixed with an explicit forall quantification: this can be done with
the short-hand notation (for universally quantified locally abstract type):

```
let rec f: type a.  (module T with type t = a) -> 'never = fun m -> f m
```

The reason behind this behavior is that locally abstract type should not escape
the scope of the function that introduced them. For instance, this code

```
let ext_store = ref None
let store x = ext_store := Some x
let f (type a) (x:a) = store x
```

should visibly fail because it tries to store a value of type `a`, which is a non-sensical type outside of the body of `f`.

By consequence, values with a locally abstract type can only be used by polymorphic function. For instance, this example

```
  let id x = x
  let f (x:a) : a = id x
```

is fine because `id x` works for any `x`.

The problem with a function like

```
 let rec f (type a) (m: (module T with type t = a)) = f m
```

is then that the type of `f` is not yet generalized inside its body, because type generalization in ML happens at `let` definition. The fix is therefore to explicitly tell to the compiler that `f` is polymorphic in its argument:

```
 let rec f: 'a. (module T with type t = 'a) -> 'never =
   fun (type a) (m:(module T with type t = a)) -> f m
```

Here, `'a. ...` is an universal quantification that should read `forall 'a. ...`.
This first line tells to the compiler that the function `f` is polymorphic in its first argument, whereas the second line explicitly introduces the locally abstract type `a` to refine the packed module type. Splitting these two declarations is quite verbose, thus the shorthand notation combines both:

```
let rec f: type a.  (module T with type t = a) -> 'never = fun m -> f m
```

Comment: That does compile fine, but even after reading through the whole thing a couple of times I don't get it. Guess I'll read it a few more times. Thanks !